# If $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ satisfies $|f'(z)| \le M$, what can be said

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ be such that $|f'(z)| \le M$ for some constant $M$. what can be said about $f$?

this is not a homework problem. I am wondering if this can give something like lipschitz continuity.

thanks

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the notation: What is $f'(z)$? The derivative here is a $1\times 2$ matrix...

Comment: @SteveD It's standard notation for the derivative. If by $1\times 2$ matrix you mean that $a+ib:=(a,b)$ ok..It's the same..

Comment: Since $z\in\Bbb R$, it's the same as a differentiable (but not $C^1$, it appears...) curve $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^2$. Using MVT on the components you get that $f$ is indeed Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: $f(z)\neq \cos z, \sin z $ because in $\Bbb{C}$ the $\cos z, \sin z $ functions are not bounded. Indeed, since $\sin z=\frac1{2i}(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})$, for $z=10i$, $|\sin 10i|\gt10^4$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write $f(t)=f_1(t)+i f_2(t)$, then
\begin{align}
|f(t)-f(s)|&=\left((f_1(t)-f_1(s))^2+(f_2(t)-f_2(s))^2\right)^{1/2}\\ \ \\
&=\left( f_1'(c_1)^2(t-s)^2+f_2'(c_2)^2(t-s)^2\right)^{1/2}\\ \ \\
&=\left( f_1'(c_1)^2+f_2'(c_2)^2\right)^{1/2}\,|t-s|\\ \ \\
&=(|f'(c_1)|+|f'(c_2)|)\,|t-s|\\ \ \\
&=2 M |t-s|.
\end{align}